# Assigning value type vs reference type

Tags: go

I am calling this method that returns type `map[int64]Block` and I am a bit confused how to properly do this in Go. In Java higher abstract types are pass by reference and can be reassigned. Here I am getting an error when I try to assign variable to a structure type.

```
storageNodes[id].blocks = initBlock()
..
func initBlock() map[int64]Block {
    block := make(map[int64]Block)
    block[0] = generateBlockOfRandomFiles()
    return block
}
..
type StorageNode struct {
    *Node
    blocks map[int64]Block
}
```

Here it's stopping me from initializing blocks value -  `Cannot assign to storageNodes[id].blocks`. Why is that?

EDIT---
The `...` just means that there's code in between. `StorageNode` is in a different file.
EDIT2---
This is what I have now:

```
        storageNodes[id].blocks = initBlock()
...
func initBlock() map[int64]*Block {
    block := make(map[int64]*Block)
    block[0] = generateBlockOfRandomFiles()
    return block
}
```

I am still getting an error when I try assign `storageNodes` to a point that is passed back from the function.

Comment: Are the assignment and the type definition in the same package?  `blocks` starting with a lowercase `b` is a private field.

Answer (score 0):

`StorageNode` and `initBlock` should be before `storageNodes[id].blocks = initBlock()`

So you can try something like this:

```
...
type StorageNode struct {
    *Node
    blocks map[int64]Block
}
...
func initBlock() map[int64]Block {
    block := make(map[int64]Block)
    block[0] = generateBlockOfRandomFiles()
    return block
}
...
storageNodes[id].blocks = initBlock()
```

Comment: Sorry I should've claried - the `...` are there to mean there is code in between. These code snippets are from different files/parts of the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `storageNodes` is of type `StoregeNode`:

You cannot assign the struct members of that map, because they are not addressable.

The definition `map[int64]Block` stores copies of `Block` structs. The expression `storageNodes[id]` returns a copy of the `Block` instance at that index. Since this is only a copy, assignments to it will be lost.

There are two ways you can solve this:

1. Declare the map as `map[int64]*Block`. This way, map indexing will return a pointer to the stored object, and you can set the values in it
2. Work on the copy, and set it back:

```
tmp:=storageNodes[id]
tmp.id=initBlock()
storageNodes[id]=tmp
```

See the definition of Addressable in the language spec:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators

It also helps to remember that, unlike Java, everything is passed by value in Go. That's why you have to explicitly pass pointers, or return pointers. The slice, map, and channel types are references to complex data types, so passing them by value passes the reference to these underlying structs.

EDIT ----
//another file
type StorageNode struct {
*Node
blocks map[int64]Block
}

```
modified code:
            storageNodes := make(map[int64]StorageNode)
            //some code b/t
            tempBlocks := make(map[int64]Block)
            tempBlocks[0] = GenerateBlockOfRandomFiles()
            storageNodes[int64(id)].blocks = tempBlocks //error Cannot assign to storageNodes[int64(id)].blocks
```

Comment: Your second option doesn't work. I still get a 'unaddressable' error when I try to assign the `StorageNodes` to the `tmp`.

Comment: Show your modified code. Also show how StorageNodes is defined.